# Accepting User Input Using Python To Return JSON entry from an API

Tags: python, json, api, exception, user-input

```
import requests

url = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'
response = requests.get(url)
users = response.json()

id_num = input("Please enter id number:")
user_name = input("Please enter username:")

for person in users:
    if person[id_num].title == person[user_name].title:
        try:
            print(person["name"])
        except AttributeError:
            print("Input doesn't match out records.")
```

Result:

```
C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\foldername\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/username/PycharmProjects/foldername/foldername/main.py
    Please enter id number:1
    Please enter username:Bret
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\foldername\foldername\main.py", line 11, in <module>
        if person[id_num].title == person[user_name].title:
    KeyError: '1'
    
    Process finished with exit code 1
```

So, I'm trying to ask the user to provide the requested input to return the name entry of the JSON file from the API. I've tried switching the variables around because it was saying KeyError Bret. then I added `.title` to take care of user error typing in the requested information. then I added the `try/except` which I have to have in there anyway. still this KeyError with first accepted input.

I'm using latest pycharm with requests installed. from the demo I'm working from I'm not suppose to import anything else, the code does work when its just

```
for person in users:
    print(person["name"])
```

but that of course returns all the names in the JSON file from the API. I need to accept user input and return the name from that, I know I'm missing something just don't know what. This is only my third project with python. I've done csv, xml, and dictionary iterations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this would give you the answer you are looking for:

```
for person in users:
    if(person["id"]==int(id_num)):
        person_username = person["username"]
        if(person_username == user_name):
            print(person["name"])
```

Basically, this issue was in this piece of code: `person[id_num].title`.

Say, your id_name = 1. Now, what you were trying to do here is get the value of the key from the person dictionary, where the key = 1. Since this was not a valid key present in the person dictionary, it resulted in a KeyError.

Now, in the code given above, what were are first checking is if the value of the person's id is equal to the  id_num input or not. If this is true, then we are fetching the username value of the person having id = id_num value. After which, we are checking if the extracted username value of the person is equal to the username input provided!